# Lucene.net 4.8 sort returns doc with NULL fields. Invalidating sort

Tags: c#, lucene, lucene.net

Using Lucene.Net, the indexer index object with a field in Document specifically used for sorting like this :

`new TextField("lastname-sort", person.LastName.RemoveDiacritics(), Field.Store.NO)`

However when searching with sort using `new SortField("lastname-sort", SortFieldType.STRING, false)` will return some scoreDocs (the first ones) with fields to `null`, which is odd to me.

After researching in the doc (https://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/4.8.0-beta00005/api/Lucene.Net/Lucene.Net.Search.Sort.html?q=sort) - that is not up-to-date, because using new Field is deprecated and using Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED is also deprecated... and Stackoverflow, I do not find any answer ...

Note that if the fields of the ScoreDocs hits are not null, they are correctly sorted.

EDIT :
Here is how the sort is made, roughly. Code is simplified. query is not null, searcher, reader and sort are not null.

Document contains a field for sorting, and multiple other stored fields:

```cs
var doc = new Document 
{
  new TextField("lastname-sort", person.LastName.RemoveDiacritics(), Field.Store.NO),
  //other fields
}
```

sort:

```cs
var sort = new Sort(new SortField("lastname-sort", SortFieldType.STRING));
```

search:

```cs
TopDocs hits = _indexSearcher!.Search(query, _nrtIndexReader!.NumDocs, sort)
```

In the hits results, the top X ScoreDocs (a dozen out of 6000 - always the same) have all their Document's fields to NULL (they are not NULL when indexed).

```cs
var indexedPersons = hits.ScoreDocs.Select(hit => _indexSearcher.Doc(hit.Doc)).Select(document =>
            {
                return new IndexedPerson
                {
                    Uid = document.Get("uid"),
                    FirstName = document.Get("firstname"),
                    LastName = document.Get("lastname"),
                    // Some Other Fields
                };
            }).ToList();
```

Note UID is not NULL, which allow us to retrieve the other values from the DB.

Comment: Sorting should have nothing to do with filtering. I would be very surprised if I sort some dataset and the result has less items than before sorting. So I don't see how null values are related here.

Comment: Do you use Field.Store.YES on the fields you expect not to be null when returned from the search?

Comment: @SimonMourier None of the fields of the document are supposed to be null, therefore all Field.Store values are Field.Store.YES

Except for the "sort" fields where it is not stored, but are not supposed to be null either.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could provide a short piece of code that demonstrates what you see as an issue.  I suspect this is a programmer misconception rather then a bug.  But I'd need to see some code to say for sure.

Comment: @RonC : I'm not sure which piece of code you'd want to see, but I'll edit my post and add what I think is relevant.

Comment: @Cromm That helps some, in that I can better understand what you think you are seeing but honestly what's needed is a small chunk of code, preferably in the form of a unit test that can demonstrate the issue.  The code would create the index, insert some docs, and query/sort them they way you need and show that the field is null that shouldn't be. This allows other devs to spot the error in the code if it exists, and if no coding error exists then it provides a crystal clear way to show what bug needs fixed in LuceneNET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The null fields were returned because of this analyzer used to index and search :

`private readonly StandardAnalyzer _standardAnalyzer = new(AppLuceneVersion);`

Meaning some lastname (Will, To, etc.) were considered stopWords. fields are therefore set to NULL and the sort would sort them like the field was empty (null).

Modifying to `private readonly StandardAnalyzer _standardAnalyzer = new(AppLuceneVersion, CharArraySet.EMPTY_SET);` solved the issue.